# Liquibase: changeLog inheritance checksum failed

Tags: database, liquibase

I've split the [Liquibase](http://liquibase.org) *changeLog.xml* that has became to huge into *sub-changeLogs.xml* (one by application version).

But unexpectedly, the checksum validation has failed on already applied `changeSet`.

After investigation, it seems that Liquibase uses a same checksum (computed on ???) for all `changeSet` of all sub-changelog.xml that declares a sql file (`<sqlFile ... />`)...

Have I miss something or is it an unsupported feature by Liquibase?

Thanks

---

#### original changelog.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<databaseChangeLog xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-3.1.xsd">

    <!-- ... -->

    <changeSet id="PIETRAN-1682" author="liquibase" logicalFilePath="scripts/2.38.0/PIETRAN-1682.sql">
        <sqlFile relativeToChangelogFile="true" path="scripts/2.38.0/PIETRAN-1682.sql" />
    </changeSet>

    <changeSet id="PIETRAN-1682-2" author="liquibase" logicalFilePath="scripts/2.38.0/PIETRAN-1682-2.sql">
        <sqlFile relativeToChangelogFile="true" path="scripts/2.38.0/PIETRAN-1682-2.sql" />
    </changeSet>

    <changeSet id="PIE-10938" author="liquibase" logicalFilePath="scripts/2.38.0/PIE-10938.sql">
        <sqlFile relativeToChangelogFile="true" path="scripts/2.38.0/PIE-10938.sql" />
    </changeSet>

    <changeSet id="version-2.38.0" author="liquibase" logicalFilePath="n/a tag=2.38.0">
        <tagDatabase tag="2.38.0"/>
    </changeSet>


    <changeSet id="2.39.0-dml" author="liquibase" logicalFilePath="scripts/2.39.0/2.39.0-ddl.sql">
        <sqlFile relativeToChangelogFile="true" path="scripts/2.39.0/2.39.0-ddl.sql"/>
    </changeSet>

    <changeSet id="PIE-10894" author="liquibase" logicalFilePath="scripts/2.39.0/PIE-10894.sql">
        <sqlFile relativeToChangelogFile="true" path="scripts/2.39.0/PIE-10894.sql"/>
    </changeSet>

    <changeSet id="PIE-10915" author="liquibase" logicalFilePath="scripts/2.39.0/PIE-10915.sql">
        <sqlFile relativeToChangelogFile="true" path="scripts/2.39.0/PIE-10915.sql"/>
    </changeSet>

    <changeSet id="version-2.39.0" author="liquibase" logicalFilePath="n/a tag=2.39.0">
        <tagDatabase tag="2.39.0"/>
    </changeSet>

    <!-- ... -->
</databaseChangeLog>
```

#### split changelog.xml

master-changelog.xml

```
<!-- ... -->
<include relativeToChangelogFile="true" file="scripts/2.38.0/changeLog.xml" />
<include relativeToChangelogFile="true" file="scripts/2.39.0/changeLog.xml" />
<!-- ... -->
```

- changelog-2.38.xml

  Contains the four first `changeSet`
- changelog-2.39.xml

  Contains the four last `changeSet`

### Checksum comparison

```html
<style type="text/css">
  .tg {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
  }
  .tg td {
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    padding: 10px 5px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    overflow: hidden;
    word-break: normal;
  }
  .tg th {
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: normal;
    padding: 10px 5px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    overflow: hidden;
    word-break: normal;
  }
  .tg .tg-hgcj {
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center
  }
  .tg .tg-uhkr {
    background-color: #ffce93
  }
  .tg .tg-lkh3 {
    background-color: #9aff99
  }
</style>
<table class="tg">
  <tr>
    <th class="tg-hgcj">id</th>
    <th class="tg-hgcj">file</th>
    <th class="tg-hgcj">description</th>
    <th class="tg-hgcj">md5sum (ORIGINAL)</th>
    <th class="tg-hgcj">md5sum (NEW)</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-031e">PIETRAN-1682.sql</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">scripts/2.38.0/PIETRAN-1682.sql</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">sqlFile</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">7:dd1a94fb6b9da96990ece716ad312b3f</td>
    <td class="tg-uhkr">7:f5032ab5d66464c5d77ca62f90ca05ad</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-031e">PIETRAN-1682-2</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">scripts/2.38.0/PIETRAN-1682-2.sql</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">sqlFile</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">7:73422229ea186af5f8500ff160ef45d5</td>
    <td class="tg-uhkr">7:f5032ab5d66464c5d77ca62f90ca05ad</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-031e">PIE-10938.sql</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">scripts/2.38.0/PIE-10938.sql</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">sqlFile</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">7:9ade6099c24da620a6b67d00d9ea9942</td>
    <td class="tg-uhkr">7:f5032ab5d66464c5d77ca62f90ca05ad</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-031e">version-2.38.0</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">n/a tag=2.38.0</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">tagDatabase</td>
    <td class="tg-lkh3">7:9895aaa1ae62f6b2dd79573f3f207f39</td>
    <td class="tg-lkh3">7:9895aaa1ae62f6b2dd79573f3f207f39</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-031e">2.39.0-dml</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">scripts/2.39.0/2.39.0-ddl.sql</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">sqlFile</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">7:f5032ab5d66464c5d77ca62f90ca05ad</td>
    <td class="tg-uhkr">7:f5032ab5d66464c5d77ca62f90ca05ad</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-031e">PIE-10894</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">scripts/2.39.0/PIE-10894.sql</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">sqlFile</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">7:666e799f34604f7daf85a54bb79e51cc</td>
    <td class="tg-uhkr">7:f5032ab5d66464c5d77ca62f90ca05ad</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-031e">PIE-10915</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">scripts/2.39.0/PIE-10915.sql</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">sqlFile</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">7:502ec7315f0d16cd6533aa4a475adc02</td>
    <td class="tg-uhkr">7:f5032ab5d66464c5d77ca62f90ca05ad</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-031e">version-2.39.0</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">n/a tag=2.39.0</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">tagDatabase</td>
    <td class="tg-lkh3">7:ea227f77515580448821fd4517f5c96f</td>
    <td class="tg-lkh3">7:ea227f77515580448821fd4517f5c96f</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

---

### UPDATE

I've opened an [issue](https://liquibase.jira.com/browse/CORE-2247) on the bug tracker of the Liquibase team and the problem will be fixed in the version 3.4.

Comment: Can you explain which checksum is which? What is `tg-031e` and what is `tg-uhkr`? I would expect liquibase to calculate a checksum for each changeset which is calculated from attributes only taken from the changeset. So it should make no difference if you spilt your changeset file as long as all attributes on the changeset remain the same. But obviously this does not seem to be the case.

Comment: In the first hand, the first column (`tg-031e` ~ *md5sumOriginal*) corresponds to _checksum_ computed when all `changeSet` were in one _changelog.xml_ file and, in the other hand, the second colum (`tg-uhkr` ~ *md5sumNew*) corresponds to _new computed checksum_ when `changeSet` have been split into _sub-changlog.xml_.  
And like you, I was expecting that moving changeSet (without having updated the changeSet attributes & the sql file itself) will not produce a checksum violation...